# CometD: Use SSL/TLS

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, cometd

How do I enable secure connections with CometD?

I have an app that is working when I use an `"http"` protocol for the BayeuxServer.  If I switch to `"https"`, I get failed handshakes.

What is the correct way to use a secure connection in CometD?

This is via the Java Client.

Here is the error:

```
{failure={exception=java.lang.NullPointerException, message={ext={ack=true}, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling],  channel=/meta/handshake, id=4, version=1.0}, connectionType=long-polling}, channel=/meta/handshake, id=4, subscription=null, successful=false}
```

I do not see any exceptions on the server (ie, the null pointer is not in our code), and if I use HTTP, it works fine.

---

I've pieced together the following for the Java client side:

```
 SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
            sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true); // only interacting with our backend, so accept self-signed certs

            WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
            webSocketClient.start();
            ClientTransport wsTransport = new JettyWebSocketTransport(null, null, webSocketClient);

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
            httpClient.start();
            ClientTransport httpTransport = new LongPollingTransport(null, httpClient);
```

I believe that will do it.

I still need to figure out how to configure the server side cometd to accept the secure connections.  I am using the Spring setup.

---

The answer to the server side is: Its a pain in the ass.

Here is how you can get it working with the jetty maven plugin:

http://juplo.de/configure-https-for-jetty-maven-plugin-9-0-x/#comment-53352

Comment: Did you configure the client with an `SslContextFactory` ? Did you configure the server to support TLS ? It's just a configuration problem, CometD works fine with TLS.

Comment: @sbordet I don't see SslContextFactory in the docs.  I don't see any info on TLS in there at all, just a mention.  Should I be looking in javadocs?

Comment: The Java client side you added is ok (well for tests since you set `trustAll=true`). As for the server, just look at the server docs on how to setup TLS for the server you are using.

Comment: @sbordet Am I mistaken in thinking trustAll is OK, given that it is our client that will only ever talk to our server?  Shouldn't it be ok to accept the self-signed cert in that case?

Comment: it all depends on what level of security you want. If you don't verify the certificate, you may not be connecting where you think you are. Just google for the various attacks that can be done. If you have a controlled environment such as a test environment, then it can be okay.